# Pass variables to a pre-defined jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function

Ok, so I have:

```
function myfunc(foo,bar) {
    $('#div' + foo).hide();
    $('#div' + bar).show();
    return false;
}
```

Then I have:

```
function myOtherFunc() {
// define vars foo and bar
    myfunc(foo,bar);
}
var timerId = setInterval(myOtherFunc, 5000); // run myOtherFunc every 5 seconds.
```

which works fine. But the I have:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){
// define vars 'foo' and 'bar'
myfunc(foo,bar);
return false;
});
```

Which doesn't work at all... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens? How are you defining the variables?

Comment: How does it fail? JavaScript error? Silently?

Comment: Where are foo and bar defined? Have you tried debugging with Firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since bb will be of type String, foo will be a string, and Javascript will cast the value 1 into a string when you perform the + operator. You can simply change this to;

```
var aa = $('.mydiv').attr('id'); // get current div's ID
var bb = aa.substring(6,7); // extract the number of the id, i.e. div1 will return '1'
var foo = bb;
var bar = parseInt(foo) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the JavaScript handles type conversion. try parsing foo into an int. `parseInt(foo, 10)`